# How to fix diagonal lines in pcsx(r)

Tags: ps1, pcsxr

I'm using the PCSXR emulator(over linux/amd64) and every time I boot any ISO/original disc/BIOS it display a diagonal line over the UI elements of the game.

[image: screenshot showing diagonal lines across UI]

I know it's because the PSX does not use sprites likes other old system but everything is a polygon. And testing with the openGL plug-in/driver, and the small FPS UI the Fi toggle button, is able to fix half of those lines but not all.

[image: screenshot showing only half of diagonal lines across UI]

So, anyone knows how to fix this issue and what mean the Fi field?